# merge two arrays and assign values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapreduce

how can I merge two arrays and assign the value from array B to all from array a[x] like this:

```
var areas = [];
var values = [];
values[0] = "aaa";
values[1] = "bbb";
areas[0] = ["A","B","C"];
areas[1] = ["D","E","F"];
```

and the expected value would be:

```
array_three[0] = ["A" => "aaa","B" => "aaa", "C" => "aaa"];
array_three[1] = ["D" => "bbb","E" => "bbb", "F" => "bbb"];
```

Do I have to use map or forEach for that?

Comment: A simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `reduce` like this:

```js
var areas = [
  ["A","B","C"],
  ["D","E","F"]
];
var values = ["aaa", "bbb"];

var result = values.map(function(value, i) {
  return areas[i].reduce(function(obj, area) {
    obj[area] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```

Or shortly using ES6's arrow functions:

```js
var areas = [
  ["A","B","C"],
  ["D","E","F"]
];
var values = ["aaa", "bbb"];

var result = values.map((value, i) => areas[i].reduce((obj, area) => (obj[area] = value, obj), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: missing a `return`